# Highcharts: How to add multiple lines on the same x-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using highcharts to create a multiple axes graph. I know it doesn't make sense since there is no comparison between the data. But still I'm required to do so.

So now what I want is that the orange line passing through the bars. I don't want it to pass through all the bars. Instead I want the orange line to be on each bar from top to bottom. So I want this orange line to only go through the top of abc, qwe and xyz individually and end on the bottom. So basically I want to have multiple lines on the same x-axis. I don't want the same line to go through all the bars. But each has its own vertical line which only starts from the top edge of the bar and ends at the bottom edge of the bar.

How can I do that. Any help will be appreciated. Here's my code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide your dashed series into 3 dashed series. Then you can use x parameter to set the value on axis where your lines should be at. for example you can set

```
{
    name: 'Average',
    type: 'fakeLine',
    color: 'orange',
    dashStyle: 'shortdash',
    data: [{
      name: 'QWE',
      x: 0.84,
      y: 3000
    }, {
      name: 'QWE',
      x: 1.2,
      y: 3000
    }],
    stack: '',
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return ' ' + this.point.name + ":" + this.point.y + '<br />'
      }
    },
  },
```

And have one line going only from top to bottom of your middle column.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/dto3Lt1f/3/

Comment: Yes thanks, thats what I was looking for. But since I have divided the values into two values one for top and one for bottom. So when I use a datalabel with this. It also shows two values one at the top and one at the bottom. How can I hide one value and show only one at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: @AkashKumar You can change your tooltip formatter to show only for bottom points. To do it you can return false for top points and return normal string for bottom points. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dto3Lt1f/4/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the all the help. I've already tried doing that. But what I want is to keep the tooltips as they are. I've tried and made the bottom series now in the tooltip this 0 value. Also shows, is there any way to hide these 0 values from the tooltip. Please check the code i've updated a new code into my question.

Comment: @ Grzegorz Blachliński Hi, the fiddle you provided still shows the bottom values in the tooltip. How can I hide the bottom values from the tooltip and only show the top values in the divided series. I even tried to make the bottom values 0 and put an if condition to check if the value is 0 then rerurn false in the formatter of the tooltips but that didn't work either. Can you please help. if(this.point.value == 0){ return false}

Comment: Is there anyway in the updated code to check if the bottom values are 0 if they are then don't display the tooltip. I tried with the formatter using an if condition but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can remove it by using tooltip formatter. You can check index of your point and if it will be equal to 1 you can remove it by returning false. You can also use marker.states.hover.enabled = false to avoid showing tooltip when you will hover this points. example: http://jsfiddle.net/dto3Lt1f/7/